# Saving version comments with paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I have a model (`Candidate`) that I need to keep track of changes, version diffs, who changed it and any comments they had regarding the change.  I love paper_trail and it is exactly what I need in almost every way, but I'm wondering what the best way to store "change comments" is.  I've been thinking of implementing one of three options:

1. Add a `comments` column to my `versions` table.  If I went this way I'm not quite sure of the best way to actually update that information.  Maybe `candidate.version.comments = @comments` would work?  Is it bad to add custom columns to paper_trail's table?
2. Use paper_trail's metadata to store the comment.  It doesn't seem like this was the intention for the metadata, but maybe it would work?
3. Add another table as `belongs_to :candidate` that would keep track of the `comments` and `version`. This seems gross - would I also need to have this new table belong to the versions table?

Any insight would be much appreciated.  I've been pretty focused on finding a solution with paper_trail since I've used it before but I'd also consider other gems or options that you've used in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up going with option 1.  I created a migration to add a comments field to the version table and added the following to `CandidatesController#update`

```
if @candidate.update(candidate_params)
    #Add comments if they are available
    @candidate.reload.versions.last.update(comments: params[:comments]) unless params[:comments].empty?
```

It seems to be working great but I'd appreciate any other thoughts that you have!

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on this from the docs, but it seems to me that using paper_trail's metadata _does_ require adding columns to your versions table?